# Xubuntu 13.04 X Login Loop

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, login, login-screen

All of a sudden, I am no longer able to login to an X session in my Xubuntu 13.04 install. The graphical login accepts my password, the screen goes blank and then returns to the login prompt. A bit of Googling tells me that this isn't an uncommon problem, but all the advice I've read so far hasn't worked:

- I can login to the guest account, so the login manager is working.
- I can login to my account via tty or ssh, so my account isn't locked.
- I can start applications through an X tunnel (XMing+PuTTY), if that's relevant.
- There's *masses* of disk space left.
- My `~/.Xauthority` is owned by me, rather than root.
- There's no reference to `~/.ICEauthority` in my logs and the file is otherwise owned by me.
- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` looks OK(ish): There are a few warnings about missing fonts and complaints about `psb`. Apparently that's the video driver (my laptop uses Intel GMA500) and there are similar complaints later in the file, however it ultimately settles on something. After all, the display is clearly working at the login screen (as it is for the guest account).
- There are some errors and permission complaints in `~/.xsession-errors`, but I'm not sure if they're relevant:

  ```
  ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Dbusmenu
  ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Unity
  ...
  ###!!! [Parent][RPCChannel] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
  ...
  debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
  ```
- I tried `dpkg-reconfigure xubuntu-desktop` and `apt-get -y install xubuntu-desktop` to try refreshing/reinstalling, but neither option seemed to do anything.

Therefore, I'm kind of at a loss! So any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: Something changed the owner of .Xauthority to root while I was playing with xrdp, xfreerdp, and vino. Thanks for listing your steps!

Comment: authority problem is discussed here https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solved the problem:

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
```

So it looks like the problem was with some desktop setting, somewhere.

Now, of course, my desktop is reset for apparently no good reason. [Is there an easy way to find the corrupted config file(s)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350752/how-to-find-corrupted-config-files)

Comment: I had this problem with new Xubuntu 13.10 after unplugging a second display at my Laptops vga-out and restarting. In my case `rm ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` did it!

Comment: Just to confirm: I had the same problem as elf12, and the command given worked for me. However, through some weird trick of my browser, it looked like there was a space in the command right after the 'l' of channel. So, note to users of this command: there are no spaces after the 'rm'! I recommend putting this command into your ~ folder as a bash shell script, so it's easy to ctl-alt-f1 into the cli, execute the bash shell script, and then ctl-alt-f7 back into the gui.

Answer (score 7):

In my case login was possible again after removing $HOME/.Xauthority :

1. Press `<ALT-Control-F1>` and you get an ASCII login. Enter username and password.
2. Type `rm .Xauthority`. Then you can go back to the graphical login screen by pressing `<ALT-Control-F7>`.

After taking a closer look it appears that the contents of .Xauthority are destroyed by *sshd* when login in from a remote machine:

> before ssh-ing from a remote machine:
>
> ls -l .Xauthority
>
> rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 50 Nov 24 18:46 .Xauthority
>
> after ssh-ing from a remote machine:
>
> ls -l .Xauthority
>
> -rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 101 Nov 24 19:22 .Xauthority

What can be seen is that the file has an odd number of bytes after the ssh-login.

Maybe there are more programs besides *sshd* that damage .Xauthority.

Comment: Hi, this happened to me also in Xubuntu 18.04.2. Not only the `.Xauthority` file, but also other files were suddently owned by root:root. Does anybody know why this happens? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but none of the above worked for me. The solution i found, was to delete a curropted file i had on desktop (in console mode) and then i could make login normal again.

Comment: AU values and encourages [high-quality answers](/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, your answer is not very useful, because a reader cannot understand how to identify such a “corrupted file”. To improve your answer can you please describe, what you did exactly?

Comment: This  solved the problem for me, after trying every other method found here or elsewhere. I don't know either, how to identify the offending file. I just deleted all the unimportant files on my desktop and luckily that worked. No need to change `.Xauthority`, `.ICEblabla`, no need to delete anything in the `.config` dir. Thanks, Absintu, for writing the answer, even though it's not that elaborate.