# Completely black screen after disconnecting external display except when booting in recovery mode

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, display

When trying to connect an external screen (video projector) to my laptop (Dell Latitude E6530), I tried to switch to the external display using Settings Manager -> Display.  I changed a setting, but I don't remember exactly which.  Then, both screens went blank.  Since then, after booting and logging in to gdm, the display is completely black.  I am able to switch to the text console and applications appear to be running.  The [Ubuntu wiki Blank screen troubleshooting page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen) states that:

> If it occurs *after* entering your password on the login page, you have some different class of issue, such as an issue with 3D / DRM. Try disabling compiz (sudo chmod a-x /usr/bin/compiz), logging in as a different user, or turning off DRI.

I am not using compiz.  I am able to log in as a guest user.  No file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` has a recent modification date.  I am able to log in successfully in recovery mode, although I get once again a blank screen if I resume from suspension.  Unlike other problems reporting blank screens after login ([1](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/xfce-blank-screen-on-login-826706/), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350692/xubuntu-13-04-x-login-loop), [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=965547), [4](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7669), [5](https://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/78239-xfce-black-screen.html)), I have no mouse cursor.  When in recovery mode, I can't change any settings through System Manager -> Display.

How do I repair my "normal boot" display configuration?  Evidently nothing was changed in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`; where else should I search?  What can I look for to investigate the cause in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [this comment by user @elf12 to an answer by @Xophmeister to their own question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350692/xubuntu-13-04-x-login-loop#comment475478_350747):

> I had this problem with new Xubuntu 13.10 after unplugging a second display at my Laptops vga-out and restarting. In my case rm ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml did it!